# Apache Drill and databaseMetadata.getColumns: Values for catalog / schema?

Tags: jdbc, apache-drill

I am trying to use drill via JDBC, but I have problems using the databasemeta-interface.

I am accessing a mongodb database (called HR) and a collection called EMPLOYEES (we copied Oracle’s HR schema into mongo to test if our code is portable to NoSQL and other non-RDBMS-sources via Apache drill)

Querying the table like `Select * from mongo.HR.EMPLOYEES` works fine, but how can I access the databasemetadata?

When I try to use the method 
`getColumns()` (catalog=null, Schema = „mongo.HR“, table=“EMPLOYEES“), I only receive an empty resultset.

I also tried to set catalog=mongo, Schema=HR, table=EMPLOYEES, but had no success?

Any idea, who I could get the column metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation of [`DatabaseMetaData.getColumns`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), it says:

> `catalog` - a catalog name; must match the catalog name as it is
>   stored in the database; `""` retrieves those without a catalog; `null`
>   means that the catalog name should not be used to narrow the search
>   `schemaPattern` - a schema name pattern; must match the schema name as
>   it is stored in the database; `""` retrieves those without a schema;
>   `null` means that the schema name should not be used to narrow the
>   search

Or, in other words, if you don't know what to use, then use `null` for `catalog` and `schemaPattern`. A compliant JDBC driver should then drop (ignore) the condition. You can then check the values of `TABLE_CAT` and `TABLE_SCHEM` to see what values catalog and schema actually have for columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For people interested in the result, the value for Catalog is "DRILL", the schema pattern in "mongo.HR".

Comment: Sorry, had to reopen again. The resultset has only 1 row. TABLE_NAME , TABLE_CAT and TABLE_SCHEM show the expected values, but COLUMN_NAME is "*". The mongo database is called HR, the collection EMPLOYEES. Querying the collection in the apache drill web client shows all expected fields.

Comment: @AlexHauskrecht I don't use MongoDB nor drill, so I don't know the specifics. If I had to guess, the problem is probably that presence or absence of columns is not deterministic for drill (or mongodb) as it's mostly schemaless, so it doesn't report them.

Comment: I am afraid that you are right. I expected Apache Drill to implement the whole JDBC interface since they provide full SQL 2003 support for a lot of Non-RDBMS-Sources including MongoDB. But the returned Column name "*" looks like a workaround in case someone intends to get a list of the table's fields to build an sql statement.
This is not what I need here, but I rate my question as answered. Thanks a lot for your support.